# Calling findOne() method returns all document fields instead of just some of them

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Trying to call a mongo collection in a Meteor App to retrieve a document using `collection.findOne({_id:"someID"},{"projection_1":1, _id:0})`

This returns the whole document instead of just `projection_1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to place this `{"projection_1":1}` into `fields`:

```js
collection.findOne({ _id: "someID" }, { fields: { "projection_1": 1 } });
```

Comment: I thought you couldn't simultaneously include and exclude fields? `_id: 0`